# How to find sophisticated C++ query module resources for development, similar to networkx?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm currently looking to develop a little more sophisticated query module in C++ and am in need of resources or examples to use as a foundation. I'm aware of the standard documentation and examples provided in C++ docs, I'm searching for something more comprehensive or advanced.

Also I'm interested in finding a library or tool in C++ that offers functionality similar to `networkx` in Python, specifically for working with Memgraph. Does anyone know of a library like to `graph-tools` but for C++ that would suit this purpose?

EDIT: *To clarify, I'm looking for resources beyond the basic examples often found in the official documentation, something that could offer insight into more complex implementations or use cases.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out how MAGE algorithms were implemented https://github.com/memgraph/mage/tree/main/cpp, but they are not really complex. This brings me to the question about complex one, there are a few complex query modules in Mage, for example https://github.com/memgraph/mage/tree/main/cpp/pagerank_module page rank. You could follow any of the developed as a basis of your work. mgp::Graph is just a wrapper around the C-api mgp_graph, this might be helpful https://memgraph.com/docs/custom-query-modules/cpp/cpp-api#graph, if you want to see how it was implemented I suggest checking out this file which contains the C++ api, just search for class graph in the code for example https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/blob/master/include/mgp.hpp.